# Can not connect to rabbitmq server in docker with error:Connection refused

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I just wrote a sprint boot application to connect the rabbitmq and tried to send some test messages, but the connection just be refused.
Rabbitmq was installed in the docker which pulled by command `docker pull rabbitmq:3-management`,

and I started it with command 
`docker run -d --hostname rabbit_test --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management`。
However, I can access the web management application with http://ip:15672 and http://localhost:15672.

Here are my configuration in springboot:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=ip # I tried with localhost and it just did not work
spring.rabbitmq.port=5762
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirms=true
```

BTW, I have googled but no helpful information.

Comment: i run the same but i can connect. using vm or which os?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is the spring application packaged inside docker?

Comment: I have solved this problem with another port.It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port of rabbitmq server is 5672. Try to use 5672 port